# Upgrading Mysql 5.1 to 5.5 on existing database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1

I need to upgrade mYsql 5.1 to 5.5 with existing database.When i searched in other sites,i found that we need to export full dump of the existing database and after upgrading,we need to import the full dump again.The existing database size is more than 1 TB.If we trying to export dump of this,it will take more time.How can we upgrading mysql 5.5 without exporting dump of the existing database?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming within the scope defined in the [help]